# Unix Shell - Understanding the use of parenthesis for variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, parentheses

I am new to Unix Shell scripting and I am kind of confused about in what cases do I have to use these type of parenthesis.
Assume that `abc` is a variable consisting of a string. Can someone give me examples of how to use these parenthesis and when I should use them?

`abc`
`$abc`
`${abc}`
`$(abc)`
`($abc)`

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html

Comment: And you've missed a few: `(($abc))`, `$((abc))` and `$(($abc))` can have some meaning, though seldom useful ones.  Try: `abc=1+1; (($abc)); ((abc)); echo $((abc)); echo $(($abc))`.

Answer (score 9):

This is rather crude but should be a good start:

`abc` - bare word\string that can be a variable name: `abc=123`

`$abc` - reference to a variable called abc

`${abc}` - string safe variable reference `file_${abc}_name.txt`

`$(abc)` - run the command `abc` and use it's stdout in place of the `$(abc)`

`($abc)` - run the command stored `$abc` in a subshell

Assuming you are in bash read [the docs on variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.htmlhtml/parameter-substitution.html) and [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/).

Comment: `($abc)` -- in a subshell,  run the command stored in variable `abc`. IO on standard channels. I don't know what you mean by "string safe" -- the braces serve to disambiguate the variable from the following text "_name"

Comment: @glennjackman hmm actually I get a syntax error... `hi='echo hi'; echo ($hi)`

Comment: @glennjackman I mean safe because "file_$abc_name.txt" will try to find a variable named `$abc_name` not `$abc`

Comment: @AndrewWhite: `($abc)` depends on context. `arr=($abc)` is an array assignment. `($abc)` is a compound command only if `(` is the first word in the command (just like `{ $abc;}`, but you need more punctuation for braces because they're not self-delimiting characters.)

Answer (score 7):

The `$` character is used to signal that parameter expansion is to be performed on the term following. Therefore if the shell reads

`abc`

on it will be parsed as a command and the shell will try and execute that command.

If the shell sees

`$abc`

it will perform `parameter expansion` on the text `abc` and effectively substitute the value of abc in place.

`${abc}`

will also perform parameter expansion. The use of the parentheses becomes significant when you have expressions like this:

`${abc}_sometext`

versus

`$abc_sometext`

In the 1st instance the shell will perform parameter expansion on `abc`. In the second instance it will perform parameter expansion on `abc_sometext`

The `$(` tells the shell to execute whats in the braces and perform `command substitution`. In this context the `$` is not used for `parameter expansion`. So if the shell reads the following:

`$(abc)`

the shell will execute `abc` and the output from it will be substitued in place and the shell will try to execute that string.

`(` simply groups commands and executes them in a subshell. So

`(abc)`

will execute `abc` but unlike `$(abc)` it will not try and execute whatever the output of the command is. For example:

```
$ $(which ls)
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Mail  Manjaro  Music  Pictures  Public      Templates  Videos  bin  code  tmp
$ (which ls)
/usr/bin/ls
$
```